# Logarithmic Expression Addition and Subtraction with x Variables

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to solve the following log problem:

[image]

Below are my steps:

[image]

But my steps appear wrong as the solution is 6.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your mistake is $\sqrt {900x^2} \ne 900 x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(900 x^2)^{\frac 12} \ne 900(x^2)^{\frac 12}$ was your mistake.

$\log_{\sqrt3}(18x^2) - \log_{\sqrt 3}(20x^3) + \frac 12 \log_{\sqrt 3}(900 x^2)=$

$\log_{\sqrt 3}\frac {18x^2}{20x^3} + \log_{\sqrt 3} (900x^2)^{\frac 12} =$

$\log_{\sqrt 3}{\frac 9{10x}} + \log_{\sqrt 3}(30x)=$

$\log_{\sqrt 3}(\frac 9{10x}\cdot 30x)=\log_{\sqrt 3}27=$

$\log_{\sqrt 3} 3^3 =\log_{\sqrt 3} \sqrt 3^6 = 6$.